# Hyphenation Issue with ArnoPro and polyglossia

Tags: fontspec, hyphenation, polyglossia

Does anyone understand why hyphenation seems not to work as expected with Arno Pro set as main font? If you try the code with Garamond Premr Pro everything works as expected.

Thank you in advance for any tips!

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize       = 11pt,% Schriftgröße
  paper          = a4,% Papierformat
  DIV            = 10,%
  BCOR           = 5mm,%
  pagesize       = luatex,%
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[babelshorthands = true,luatexrenderer=Harfbuzz]{polyglossia}% Sprachumschaltung
% Setup
\setmainlanguage[%
 spelling            = new,%
 latesthyphen    = true
]{german}


\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[2]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{#1}\hyphenation{#2}\end{otherlanguage*}%
}

\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
%\setmainfont{Garamond Premr Pro}%[%


\sethyphenation{german}{Kom-man-di-tist-en-ver-samm-lung Ge-sell-schaf-ter-ver-samm-lung}
 \begin{document}

 \parbox{0pt}{Kommanditistenversammlung}  \vspace*{3cm}

 \parbox{0pt}{Gesellschafterversammlung}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, unfortunately I am using LuaLaTeX, i.e. that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: actually I have deleted my comment luatex is obvious as you load luaotfload:-) (although there is no need to do that lualatex loads luaotfload already in the format even if you don't use fontspec)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the information. I will stop loading luaotfload from now on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The following, simplified version of your code experiences no hyphenation issues. Maybe some of the document class options or some of the packages you load are causing some interference.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[2]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{#1}\hyphenation{#2}\end{otherlanguage*}}
\sethyphenation{german}{ Kom-man-di-tist-en-ver-samm-lung 
                         Ge-sell-schaf-ter-ver-samm-lung  }


%%% Instead of 'polyglossia', consider using 'babel':
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelhyphenation{ kom-man-di-tist-en-ver-samm-lung 
                   ge-sell-schaf-ter-ver-samm-lung  }


\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{1sp}

\begin{document}
Kommanditistenversammlung

\medskip
Gesellschafterversammlung
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that loading ArnoPro  as main font after polyglossia is causing the issue. However, it is weired to me that I get different results from different fonts loaded.

Comment: @Roadrunner85 - Your comment raises a separate question: Why are you using the `polyglossia` package? Do give `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and, if needed, `\addto\extrasngerman{\hyphenation{kom-man-di-tist-en-ver-samm-lung ge-sell-schaf-ter-ver-samm-lung}}` a try.

Comment: @Mico Or better with `\babelhyphenation`. I wonder if in this particular case `\babelpatterns` is even better.

Comment: @Mico honestly I have no specific reason for polyglossia. It was habit from the time when I worked with XeLaTeX. I am considering your suggestion to switch over to babel. Thank you. Just for your information: The MWE works as expected with babel instead of polyglossia. That should lead as to the conclusion that polyglossia has some kind of bug here, correct?

Comment: @Mico you are loading the font before polyglossia and so use the node renderer. After it would use harfbuzz. (I don't have the font and can't try myself).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. My laptop (MacBookAir Late-2019, MacOS 11.6 "Big Sur") runs MacTeX2021, LuaHBTeX `1.13.2`, LateX2e `<2021-06-01> patch level 1`, and fontspec `2020/02/21 v2.7i`. (Arno Pro is distributed automatically with MacOS.) Loading the `fontspec` package with the options `Renderer=Node`, `Renderer=Harfbuzz`, and `Renderer=OpenType` doesn't seem to make a difference in the sense hyphenation succeeds for both test words.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer adding ```\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,Common},SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer = Harfbuzz,Letters = SmallCaps}}``` directly before ```\setmainfont{ArnoPro}``` makes the MWE compile as expected even with polyglossia. So what is the conclusion? I am pretty sure that the renderer option of fontspec is causing the issue. Because setting ```renderer = node``` leads to the same problem as not setting it at all.

Comment: @Roadrunner85 I can't test. But it doesn't make sense to load lots of packages and options if you want to debug something. So remove everything and load only fontspec + set the hyphenation with \hypenation{...}. Then load the font with \setmainfont{Arno Pro}[Renderer=Harfbuzz] and check if the renderer is the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer running the MWE with only ```\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ArnoPro}[Renderer=Node] \hyphenation{Kom-man-di-tist-en-ver-samm-lung Ge-sell-schaf-ter-ver-samm-lung}```leads to a working example. Strange. If I add polyglossia to the mix and remove ```Renderer=Node``` it does no longer work as expected.

Comment: I said you should try with  `Renderer=HarfBuzz` and not load polyglossia.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's what I did first. Sorry. It leads to the error.  ```Renderer=OpenType``` does not work, too.

Comment: well so it is a problem of Arno Pro with harfbuzz. What happens with xelatex? (which uses harfbuzz too).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer running it with xelatex without renderer set makes the first word within ```\hypenation{}``` compile correctly and the second one not at all.

Comment: well if it basically works with xelatex but not with lualatex then you could report it to luaotfload.

Comment: Just a last update: The error is known to the luaotfload team for a while. See https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/152 for more information. So one has to wait for a bugfix and take care not to run into this issue without knowing it.